# JS validation, Go to a link if both inputs are correct

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I just starting programming this year and i have to do a website project with javascript validation. I know this is simple but i just forgot how to do it. Im trying to do a log in, username and password, where if the user enters admin in both it will take him to a php page and if either one is incorrect it will return false.

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" action="members.php" onsubmit="login()" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Admin Login </legend>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <br>
    <label>Password </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**note im actually lost and no idea what im doing in the js part**

```
function login () {
  var username = document.form2.value.username;
  var password = document.form2.value.password;

  if ( username === "admin") {
      alert("Incorrect");
      return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  if (password === "admin") {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know it, I can tell you, help you improve. But if you just forgot, you should grab a book and revisit it. This is way too basic if you really want to develop something with JavaScript.

Comment: I know its basic, but all i've been thought is if and else, for loops, strings and math random. If you could tell me where im going wrong would be really helpful.

Comment: The first 2 lines within the function are wrong. You didin't get the DOM elements at all. Revisit the APIs of getting elements from the document. Hint: `document.getElement...`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i knew about the getElementById but the lecturers just wrote document... etc in the examples.

Comment: Still cant get it, are the if statements correct?

Answer (score -1):

You could do this on the client in JavaScript:

```
if (login()) {
  document.location = 'members.php';
}
```

Better would be to just submit the data to the PHP-script and check it there, so nobody can read out the username/password.

```
if ('admin' === $_POST['username'] && 'admin' === $_POST['password']) {
  echo 'Hello, admin.';
} else {
  echo 'Invalid login, <a href="login.html">retry</a>.';
}
```